# python None and equals evaluation

Tags: python, operators, python-3.7

If I run the following Python 3.7 code

```
a=None
b=None
a==b
>> True
b is not None
>> False
True is not None
>> True
a==b is not None
>> False
```

since a==b is True, this makes me understand this code evaluates as A==B where A=a and B=b is not None

However, if I run the following code

```
a = datetime(2020,1,1)
b = datetime(2020,1,1)
a==True
>> False
b is not None
>> True
a==b is not None
>> True
```

it contradicts the above. So I'm puzzled a bit with how all this is evaluated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: First example `a==b is not None` is expanded to `a==b and b is not None` => `True and False` => `False`. Second example is expanded `a==b and b is not None` => `True and True` => `True`

Comment: That expansion of expressions is why Python lets you write `a < b < c`, which becomes `a < b and b < c` while most other languages just literally try to compare the `a < b` boolean to c and get nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

you are seeing operator chaining in your example,

```py
a==b is not None
```

is equivalent to:

```py
a==b and b is not None
```

Thus the result.

If you want to compare `a==b`, use an atomic expression:

```py
(a==b) is not None
```

See [6.10. Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) for details.
In short, `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.